# price of each item (data frame with only two columns item_name and item_price)

Tags: python, pandas, analytics, data-analysis

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuU6p.jpg (table link)
i have tried

```
chipo[[chipo.drop_duplicates(subset='item_name'),'item_price']
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for mask with inverting by `~`:

```
chipo.loc[~chipo.duplicated(subset='item_name'),'item_price']
```

Or first remove duplicates and then select column:

```
chipo.drop_duplicates(subset='item_name')['item_price']
```

Comment: @sanjeevnarain - Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @sanjeevnarain - [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: thanks man i got ..my bad i realize it late